# Set size line plot with different y axis as addition to a stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot stacked barplot with added line plot that presents the overall set sizes. I'm plotting stacked barplot in ggplot2 without problems however additional line with different y axis is the difficulty. I'm using long-formated table as input, so there is no 'overall size' column.

Code to reproduce sample table:

```
df <- data.frame(Sample=c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6"), A=c(30,52,50,81,23,48), B=c(12,20,15,22,30,14), C=c(rep(15,6)))
df.melt <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "Sample", variable.name = "Group")
```

Head of the table:

```
   Sample Group value
1:     S1     A    30
2:     S2     A    52
3:     S3     A    50
4:     S4     A    81
5:     S5     A    23
6:     S6     A    48
```

Code to draw stacked barplot:

```
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1), legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3") +
  ylab("% of Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits  = unique(df.melt$Sample))
```

Therefore the line would run through six stacked bars pointing the size of each set i.e. for sample S1 it would be 57 (A + B + C), and y axis labels to the right of the plot would show set size range.

[image]

Comment: Where does the set size of 57 come from?  I don't see how that can be derived from your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the data set directly in the geom. This allows you to use different data sets for each geom. Secondary axis are a bit tricky.  They need to be a function of the primary axis and the data adjusted accordingly. I've used 120 as the adjustment factor.

[image: visual]

```
percent <- c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")

set_sizes <- df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(Size = sum(A, B, C))
    
    
ggplot() +
    geom_col(df.melt, mapping = aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = Group),position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
    geom_line(set_sizes, mapping = aes(x = Sample, y = Size / 120, group = 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "% of Total", labels = percent, sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .*120, name  = "Sample Size")) +            
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1), legend.title=element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits  = unique(df.melt$Sample))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `cowplot` to arrange two independent plots on top of each other, e.g.:

```r
suppressMessages(invisible(lapply(c("data.table", "ggplot2", "cowplot"), 
    require, character.only=TRUE)))
df <- data.table(Sample=c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6"), 
    A=c(30,52,50,81,23,48), B=c(12,20,15,22,30,14), C=c(rep(15,6)))
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = "Sample", variable.name = "Group")
percent <- paste0(sprintf("%s", seq(0, 100, 25)), "%")
p1 <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1), legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3") +
  ylab("% of Total") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits  = unique(df.melt$Sample))

p2 <- ggplot(df.melt[, .(value=sum(value)), by="Sample"], 
    aes(x = Sample, y = value, group=1)) +
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
    labs(x = NULL)
plot_grid(p2, NULL, p1, align="hv", nrow=3, axis='tlbr', rel_heights=c(1, -.28, 4), greedy=FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>